# My "Shift +." combination isn't working

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys

Hello I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS and for some reasons I can't type the ">" character.
The shift key is working because I can type other things such as < or?
The. Key is working as well because I can type it, but in combination they don't work.
Can anyone tell me what should I do, I don't see any binding related to it in my keyboard Shortcuts as well

**Edit**:
for command `grep -v ^# /etc/default/keyboard  | sort -u`
the output is

```
BACKSPACE="guess"
XKBLAYOUT="us"
XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBOPTIONS=""
XKBVARIANT=""
```

for command `echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP`
output is

```
ubuntu:GNOME
```

for command `gsettings list-recursively | grep xkb`
the output is

```
org.gnome.desktop.input-sources xkb-options @as []
org.gnome.desktop.input-sources mru-sources [('xkb', 'us'), ('ibus', 'mozc-jp')]
org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources [('xkb', 'us'), ('ibus', 'mozc-jp')]
org.freedesktop.ibus.panel xkb-icon-rgba '#415099'
org.freedesktop.ibus.general xkb-latin-layouts ['ara', 'bg', 'cz', 'dev', 'gr', 'gur', 'in', 'jp(kana)', 'mal', 'mkd', 'ru', 'ua']
```

Comment: Since there is no Ubuntu 20 the right version would be a start.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the following output `grep -v ^# /etc/default/keyboard  | sort -u`, `echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` and `gsettings list-recursively | grep xkb` .

Comment: @David ah sorry, I added the complete version name

Comment: @N0rbert hello, I added the required outputs, thanks!